# What is wrong with my program? I know I have made a mistake. But where?

Tags: java, swing

When run it i get this error message in the console. Where have I gone wrong?
"Error displaying C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
public class exmpleText
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt";
        try
        {
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Hi");
            JEditorPane Pane = new JEditorPane(url);
            Pane.setEditable(false);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(Pane));
        } 
        catch(IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error displaying " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: import org.jfree.ui.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;

Comment: @John Saunders the edited versions don't work either. I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORRECTED CODE

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class exmpleText
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String url = "C:\\Users\\welcome\\z.txt";
    File f = new File(url);

    try
    {
      URL x = f.toURL();
      System.out.println(x);         

      JFrame frame=new JFrame("Hi");

      JEditorPane Pane = new JEditorPane(x);
      Pane.setEditable(false);

      frame.add(new JScrollPane(Pane));
      frame.setVisible(true);
    } 
    catch(Exception ioe) 
    {
      System.out.println(ioe);
      System.err.println("Error displaying " + url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I want to know the Control Flow and how it works.

Comment: Declaring a variable name as "url", it willnot become URL. you need a file object to open a file and then deal with it.

Answer (score 5):

Your first mistake is this line.

```
    System.err.println("Error displaying " + url);
```

The mistake is not in what it is doing, but what it is NOT doing.  What is should also be doing is printing out (at least) the exception message, and preferably the stack trace.

---

And now that you've seen / shown us the stack trace, it is clear what the underlying error is.  The string `"C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt"` is not a valid URL.  A valid file URL starts with a `"file:"` scheme.

File URLs with Windows drive letters are written like `"file:///C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt"`.

**Reference**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx

Alternatively, you can convert a pathname to a URL using `new File("some path").toURL()`.

Comment: What's wrong in that line? The error message is printing in the console. I am getting the message "Error displaying C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt".

Comment: you are printing URL which will not help in getting error. pls write  ioe.printStackTrace() to get the error. We want to know to answer ur question

Comment: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
                                                                      at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at example.main(example.java:23)
Error displaying C://Users//Nimit//Desktop//n.txt

Answer (score 3):

You should display the stacktrace in order to know what is really going on, using `ioe.printStackTrace()`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExempleText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "C:/Users/Nimit/Desktop/n.txt";
        try {
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Hi");
            JEditorPane Pane = new JEditorPane(url);
            Pane.setEditable(false);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(Pane));
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Error displaying " + url);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code  after JFrame object creation

```
 try{

editorPane.setContentType("text/html");

Reader fileRead=new FileReader(name); // name is the file you want to read

editorPane.read(fileRead,null);

} catch(Exception e) { 

e.printStackTrace();
}
```